# Removing Microsoft Store applications

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

We are trying to remove all microsoft store applications from all of users within my project.  can you kind folks please look at the script below and tell me what seems to be the issue.

```sh
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

#Uninstall blocked apps
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.WebpImageExtension* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.WindowsMaps* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.YourPhone* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.SkypeApp* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MSPaint* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Print3D* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Bing* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Xbox* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.Zune* -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Write-Output
```

[image: Error code can be viewed below]

Comment: `0x80070002` translates to "file not found" - perhaps not all users have the exact same versions installed?

Comment: Have you looked up the error to determine what it means?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure on why it doesn't work, I did find another discussion about this same error. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/65522/powershell-remove-app-package-remove-appxpackage-a.html)

Here's a sample script you can use, by adding each of your apps to the list

```
$appList = "Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection",
           "Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions",
           "Microsoft.HEVCVideoExtension",
           "Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub"

$allAppxPackages = Get-AppxPackage -PackageTypeFilter All
foreach ($app in $appList)
{
    $allAppxPackages | Where-Object {$_.PackageFullName -like "*$app*"} | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
}
```